# how to get random object from array every x sec

Tags: angularjs

I want to display an image randomly every x sec.

I have an array of images:

```
$scope.image = [{'imageUrl': 'img/1.jpg'},... {'imageUrl': 'img/10.jpg'}];

   $scope.random = function() {
    $interval(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
     }, 1000);
    };
```

and the html:

```
   <div ng-repeat="image in image | orderBy: random | limitTo: 1">
      <img ng-src="{{image.imageUrl}}" class="thumb-modal">
   </div>
```

Comment: Please explain a little more. Do you expect that this current code would work but it doesn't? If so, what errors or behavior do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate an integer from 0 to your array length, and then pick an image in your array using this index. See example:

```
$scope.images = [{'imageUrl': 'img/1.jpg'},... {'imageUrl': 'img/10.jpg'}];

$interval(function() {
  var randomIndex = Math.round( Math.random() * ($scope.images.length-1) );
  $scope.image = $scope.images[randomIndex];
}, 1000)
```

And in your HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{image.imageUrl}}" class="thumb-modal">
```

No need for ng-repeat as you only display one image!

Comment: Glad it helped you! Feel free to upvote the answer if you think it can help others.. :P thanks